# two different ethernet lan connection internet connection issue

Tags: networking, windows-8, router, ethernet, lan

I have a two lan connection:

Ethernet 1 is a my internet access.
Eherhnet 2 is our office lan connection /no internet access/

So I have problem with internet connection while I enable 'Ethernet 2' connection on adapter settings. When I disable 'Ethernet 2 adapter' then internet connection is working. I wonder what setting I missed.

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Is one cable plugged into a modem or router, and the other the LAN via a hub? Sounds like default routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you leave the default gateway blank on Ethernet 2. You should also only have the DNS server set on one adapter. If you have an active directory domain setup (or your own DNS server) on Ethernet 2 then set the DNS server their. Otherwise set it to automatically obtain on Ethernet 1 and leave it blank on Ethernet 2.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I almost solved the problem.
I leaved the default gateway blank on Ethernet 2 then Internet is coming ok.
Ethernet2 is configured by DNS server. 
I added dns server on Ethernet 2 but I can't connect oracle db server. Should I add it on Ethernet 1?

Comment: Try leaving the DNS setting on Ethernet 2 the same as when you were able to connect to the db server. Set the DNS server on Ethernet 1 to manually configured and leave it blank.